# Node.js - My image tags aren't showing pictures

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This code is supposed to show the uploaded images in the `uploads` folder which is in the root directory, where the `app.js` and `package.json` are. The image path names are saved on upload in a MySQL table. This code doesn't work. Only shows a broken image file and a `500 internal error` in Chrome. Firefox doesn't tell me anything in the console but also shows a broken image file. I believe the problem lies in the view because the server side script works perfectly and all the image paths are sent.

```
router.get('/board', function(req, res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts', function(err, result){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }else{
            res.render('board', {print: result});
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the view which I believe is the problem.

```
<% print.forEach(function(posts){ %>
        <div class="post-container">
            <h2> <%= posts.Title %> </h2>
            <hr>
            <img class="post-img" src=<%= posts.Img_path %> >
        </div>
    <% }); %>
```

Chrome shows me a broken image file and tells me `500 (Internal Server Error)` while firefox doesn't tell me anything in the console but also shows a broken image file.

Comment: Did you try enclosing the `src` value in double quotes? What is the value of `Img_path`?

Comment: it looks like there an error with your route or code that responds to client with image

Comment: I think you should show your logs

Comment: Please share the code as well which handles route for serving images

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to setup the router to be able to find the images folder. Take a look at: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html